# Krajee's file input only upload last selected image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm working with [this plugin](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input) in Codeigniter as I want to upload multiple files (either it can be multiple images, videos or files) and as mentioned there I have done the following code

### HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="attachments"></label>
     <input id="attachment" name="attachment[]" type="file" class="file" multiple>
</div>
```

### Script

```
 $("#attachment").fileinput({
        uploadUrl: '#',
        uploadAsync: false,
        showCaption: false,
        fileActionSettings: {
            showRemove: true,
            showUpload: false,
            showZoom: true,
            showDrag: false
        },
        showUpload:false,
        allowedFileExtensions: ["jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "mp4", "txt", "docx", "pptx", "xlsx", "pdf", "ppt", "xls", "doc"],
        overwriteInitial: false,
        initialPreviewAsData: true, // identify if you are sending preview data only and not the raw markup
        initialPreviewFileType: 'image', // image is the default and can be overridden in config below
        purifyHtml: true // this by default purifies HTML data for preview
    }).on('filesorted', function (e, params) {
        console.log('File sorted params', params);
    }).on('fileuploaded', function (e, params) {
        console.log('File uploaded params', params);
    });
```

But the above code is not working properly as I'm only getting the last selected image instead of getting all the selected image.

This is what I got when I do `$_FILES[]`

```
Array
(
    [attachment] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => img3.jpg
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/jpeg
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /opt/lampp/temp/phpQNpdOb
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 144544
                )

        )

)
```

I have also tried the solution mentioned on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768133/krajee-file-input-only-upload-last-selected-image) but that too didn't worked.

PS: I don't want to upload files via ajax I just want to preview all my selected files and when I press submit button I want all those files to be uploaded.

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You mean when you submit only the last file gets uploaded? If so, you should post your controller code and not just the js stuff. I'm unfamiliar with this plugin, but I'm very familiar with file uploading via php.

Comment: yes $_FILES shows only one array.

Comment: Please post full controller code not just the output :)

Comment: Using your *exact* code I get an array with all the files I added... https://pastebin.com/dB94S7Tb

Comment: The caveat being that I had to select the files at at once after hitting browse; otherwise just one showed up in the preview; but if you are seeing all your previews, you should be getting all the files in the files array

Comment: But I think that was due to "As noted earlier, when initializing plugin via javascript (step 2a), you MUST NOT attach the CSS class `file` to the input."